# Ionic Page with inputs super slow

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My ionic pages that has inputs are really slow.
a 4 item select has a delay of like 800ms. and when dismissing the keyboard, a white blank block stays on screen for 500ms.

this app has around 10 pages with forms but all my forms are really slow. please suggest better ways to implement high performance forms.

Take a look at this sample code.

Sample Code :

```
<ion-content >

  <div class="confirmform" style="padding:5px;">

    <div class="confirmitem" *ngFor="let room of rooms; let i = index;">
      <ion-item class="roomheader">
        <ion-label>Room {{i+1}} Details</ion-label>

      </ion-item>
      <!-- item -->

      <div class="adultitem" *ngFor="let adult of room.adults;let x = index">
          <ion-item >
              <ion-label>Adult {{x+1}}</ion-label>

            </ion-item>
          <ion-row>

            <ion-col>
              <ion-item style="padding-top:22px;">

                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="adult.title" style="max-width: 100%;width:100%; padding-left: 2px;" interface="popover" placeholder="Title">
                  <ion-option value="Mr">Mr</ion-option>
                  <ion-option value="Ms">MS</ion-option>
                  <ion-option value="Miss">Miss</ion-option>
                  <ion-option value="Mrs">Mrs</ion-option>

                </ion-select>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-item style="padding-top: 22px;    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;" class="checkitem">
                <ion-label>Lead Guest</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox color="dark" [(ngModel)]="adult.leadguest" tappable (click)="leadchecker(i,x)"></ion-checkbox>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="adult.fname"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="adult.lname"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

      </div>

      <!-- children -->


      <div class="adultitem" *ngFor="let child of room.children;let x = index">
        <ion-item >
            <ion-label>Children {{x+1}}</ion-label>

          </ion-item>
       <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-item style="padding-top:22px;">

              <ion-select [(ngModel)]="child.title" style="max-width: 100%;width:100%; padding-left: 2px;" interface="popover" placeholder="Title">
                <ion-option value="Master">Master</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="Miss">Miss</ion-option>

              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>

        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="child.fname"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="child.lname"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

    </div>

      <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-9>
              <p style="color:red;font-size: 12px;">Cancellation Policy :</p>
              <p style="color:red;font-size: 12px;" *ngFor="let policy of cp[i]" [innerHTML]="policy"></p>

            </ion-col>

          <ion-col col-3>
              <h2 style="color: #484343;font-size: 16px;">Cost {{currency}} {{room.total}}</h2>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>

<!-- contact section -->

<div class="confirmitem">
    <ion-item class="roomheader">
        <ion-label>Contact Info</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>

    <ion-row>

         <ion-col>
           <ion-item style="padding-top:22px;">



             <ion-label floating >Country </ion-label>
             <ion-input [(ngModel)]="contact.country.country_name" (click)="opencountry()" ></ion-input>
           </ion-item>
         </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

       <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-5>
              <ion-item>
                  <ion-label floating>Country code</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.countrycode" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
           </ion-col>

           <ion-col>
              <ion-item >
                  <ion-label floating>Mobile Number</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="contact.homephone" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

       <ion-row>
          <ion-col >
              <ion-item>
                  <ion-label floating>Email Address</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="email"  [(ngModel)]="contact.email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
           </ion-col>

           <ion-col>
              <ion-item >
                  <ion-label floating>Confirm Email</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="email"  [(ngModel)]="contact.email2" ></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

       <ion-row>
         <ion-col>
           <button ion-button color="primary" style="margin:0 auto;display:block" (click)="submitBooking()">Proceed to Booking</button>
         </ion-col>
       </ion-row>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Please suggest me a way to improve the performance of the page .

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution? I have no inline styles and testing on device with production mode in angular and --prod doesnt seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve the page's performance doing below suggestions:

1. Remove all `inline styles` and put that in relevant page's `SCSS` file or use global `app.scss` file . `Inline styles` won't cache and also very difficult to maintain the app.
2. Test your app's performance on a real device using below `CLIs` :

   ```
   ionic cordova build android --prod

   ionic cordova build ios --prod
   ```

Comment: I have tested on the production env also, but the input performance are bad .

Comment: Did you do the `1 suggestion`?

Comment: I will try it now and let you know. Thanks